# SQL - Select min and max on grouped columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I want to select the employees' start and end dates for each department using a SQL query. Taking into mind that an employee might return to a previous department.

As the system creates a new FromDate and ToDate when changes are created to (irrelevant) columns such as a new address, title each employee has several rows.

What I have:

| EmpID | DeptCode | FromDate | ToDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 40 | 2016-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 2017-08-31 00:00:00.000 |
| 201 | 40 | 2017-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 2018-09-30 00:00:00.000 |
| 201 | 80 | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2019-05-31 00:00:00.000 |
| 201 | 80 | 2019-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020-06-30 00:00:00.000 |
| 201 | 80 | 2020-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-02-28 00:00:00.000 |
| 201 | 40 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 |
| 302 | 10 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 |

What I want to achieve is

| EmpID | DeptCode | FromDate | ToDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 40 | 2016-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 2018-09-30 00:00:00.000 |
| 201 | 80 | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-02-28 00:00:00.000 |
| 201 | 40 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 |
| 302 | 10 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 |

Comment: This is a gaps and island problem. Looking up this methodology will very likely give you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, we need to create something that we can user for our group by (DBFiddle at the end of the answer)

Look at this sample

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by t.EmpID, DeptCode order by t.EmpID, t.FromDate) as seqnum_na,
       row_number() over (partition by t.EmpID order by t.EmpID, t.FromDate) as seqnum_n
from   codes t
```

the result is

| EmpID | DeptCode | FromDate | ToDate | seqnum_na | seqnum_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 40 | 2016-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 2017-08-31 00:00:00.000 | 1 | 1 |
| 201 | 40 | 2017-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 2018-09-30 00:00:00.000 | 2 | 2 |
| 201 | 80 | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2019-05-31 00:00:00.000 | 1 | 3 |
| 201 | 80 | 2019-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020-06-30 00:00:00.000 | 2 | 4 |
| 201 | 80 | 2020-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-02-28 00:00:00.000 | 3 | 5 |
| 201 | 40 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 | 3 | 6 |
| 302 | 10 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 | 1 | 1 |

Now let's look at the last 2 columns,
suppose you would subtract them from each other, you would get

| EmpID | DeptCode | seqnum_na | seqnum_n | calculated group by value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 40 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 201 | 40 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 201 | 80 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 201 | 80 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 201 | 80 | 3 | 5 | 2 |
| 201 | 40 | 3 | 6 | 3 |
| 302 | 10 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Now this "calculated group by value", we can use for our actual group by

```
select i.EmpID, i.DeptCode, min(i.FromDate) as FromDate, max(i.ToDate) as ToDate
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t.EmpID, DeptCode order by t.EmpID, t.FromDate) as seqnum_na,
             row_number() over (partition by t.EmpID order by t.EmpID, t.FromDate) as seqnum_n
      from   codes t
     ) i
group by (seqnum_n - seqnum_na), EmpID, DeptCode
order by i.EmpID, min(i.FromDate), i.DeptCode
```

Which will get you this

| EmpID | DeptCode | FromDate | ToDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 40 | 2016-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 2018-09-30 00:00:00.000 |
| 201 | 80 | 2018-10-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-02-28 00:00:00.000 |
| 201 | 40 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 |
| 302 | 10 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 |

The full code and results you can find in this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=22387585501096676d72743cbc6bf96c)